# How can a GWT app change without causing the entire thing to be downloaded again?

Tags: gwt, browser-cache

I like GWT cache control a lot, but I see a downside and I'm wondering if anyone knows of any solution/work around. If I make a small change to my app (ie. add a character to some text), GWT will rename the .cache.js file causing any cached files in the user's browser to be tossed. I was hoping code splitting would result in a small change only causing that "code split" to be re-downloaded, but GWT is renaming the folder that contains the splits so the whole thing is still downloaded. Any ideas on how to isolate changes to cause only a portion of the app to be re-downloaded?

Comment: How big is your app? I have a huge app with close to 100 different "views", over 60 data types, etc., and it compiles to 1.6MB. This is equivalent to roughly 6 seconds of an HD movie. The initial download is much smaller - 400kB. I am all in for optimizations, but unless most of your customers are on very slow connections, where is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lengthy text (e.g. an explanation, a help article, etc.), you can [externalize](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#TextResource) it. This way it won't be a part of the compiled code.

Other than this, there is currently no way to isolate changes so that only a portion of the app redownloads.